# "SMP is not supported on this platform"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, smp, bcc-bpf

I am currently trying to use an eBPF program on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2, that has Ubuntu installed. For managing the compilation, system calls and all that, I use the BPF compiler collection.

Whenever BCC tries to compile the program, I get a multitude of errors, one of which is "SMP is not supported on this platform" and another "SMP not supported on pre-ARMv6 CPUs".

This seems really strange to me, because looking at the headers, those should only occur, if __LINUX_ARM_ARCH__ is smaller than 6.

"uname -m" gives me armv7l, which should be sufficient, right?
Looking at the kernel config, CONFIG_SMP is y and CONFIG_CPU_32v7 is y as well. So as far as I understand, everything seems correct.

So why doesn't it work and how can I fix it?

Also if you need more information, I'll gladly supply it. I've never been so deep into this stuff, so I don't know what's more and what's less important.

Comment: Check that you have the same version installed for both kernel and header files. Check that you are telling the compiler of your program to use the correct kernel headers. (And the same with standard library and other libraries). If all seems OK, it may be a bug of that program (if maintainer doesn't have access to an architecture, the maintainer may not notice portability errors.

Comment: I actually did have an outdated version of the header files installed, but removing them didn't change the errors.

Comment: I poked around a bit more and tried installing the 64-bit version of ubuntu on another raspberry and repeated the same steps as before. Now, with the arm64 architecture and everything else being the same, everything works as intended. Maybe the armv7l binaries of some package I used just had errors in them... So for now I can just avoid the problem, since I only need that machine to test that program, which makes switching architecture not a problem. But thanks anyway!